# Generic function does not update the value of label in tableview cell after tableView.reloadData()

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, extension-methods, reloaddata

I have a function where I am incrementing the value of the label as below

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let indexPath = indexPath(sender: sender, tableView: profileTableView)

        array[Int((indexPath.row))].likes = String(Int(array[Int((indexPath.row))].likes)!+1)
        self.userProfileTableView.reloadData()
    }
```

In the above function after the reloadData value of the label gets incremented to the next number, But when I make it a generic function in an extension as below the value of the label does not increment

```
func buttonClicked(data:String,tableView:UITableView) {
        let data = String(Int(data)!+1)
        print("Incremented data", data)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

I am calling the function as following but the label does not get updated with the incremented value . It retains the old value.

```
buttonClicked(data: feeds[Int((indexPath.row))].likes, tableView: userProfileTableView)
```

Any help will be appreciated . Thank you.

Comment: Not a solution but why you are casting `indexPath.row` to `Int`, there is no need of it because `indexPath.row` is already of `Int` type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should change your code to this.

```
let numLikes = Int(feeds[Int((indexPath.row))].likes)!
feeds[Int((indexPath.row)).likes = String(numLikes)
```

Because `String` is a value types.

When you do this.

```
buttonClicked(data: feeds[Int((indexPath.row))].likes, tableView: userProfileTableView)

func buttonClicked(data:String,tableView:UITableView) {
    let data = String(Int(data)!+1)
    print("Incremented data", data)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

1) New value variables `data` in func `buttonClicked` will be created and has value = `feeds[Int((indexPath.row))].likes`

2) when you change `data`, it just change `data` but not `feeds[Int((indexPath.row))].likes`

Look at [Value and Reference Type](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Actually You didn't update the array object with updated value in your generic method.

Either you may have to update the incremented value in array OR send your array to the generic function with selected index.

Example:

```
func buttonClicked(feeds:[Feed], index:Int, tableView:UITableView) {

        feeds[index].likes = String(Int(feeds[index].likes)!+1)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

But I don't say this as generic function, since It's using for minimal places with minimal code and there is no generic types to reuse.

Thanks!